# Hibernate:Populating specific columns while doing insert in to Database

Tags: java, sql-server, sql-server-2008, hibernate, mapping

For persisting data used hibernate with `SQLServer`. In system every table contains four column.

```
1. Created User
2. Created Date
3. Modified User
4. Modified Date
```

From beginning system does not contain any mechanism for entering `"modified User"` and `"modified Date"` while insert and `update` operation.

My Question. is there any way in hibernate to entering **modified User** and **Modified Date** without changing every where ?

My question:

1)Is there any way to provide `user(inform of Id or bean)` to `hibernate` ?

2)If **Yes**,How can I tell to hibernate that populate this two columns while doing insert of records?

Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 1):

One way would be to change of your servlets, or rest controllers, or possibly DAO's you are writing.

A second way is to create a DAO, servlet, or rest controller that gets the user object and date and make all of your servlets/daos/controllers extend the one you just made.

It is a pain in the behind but it would be better than setting a single point of context.

Passing security context(user) and date to a DAO is pretty easy to do and would be a lot easier to maintain in the future.

Comment: What about setting the user details  to those fields of bean while inserting records ? have to do it manually in each DAO ?

Comment: @sᴜʀᴇsʜᴀᴛᴛᴀ not if you make each DAO extend a DAO that has the security context. But yes, you could do it manually in each DAO.

Comment: Its horrible if you have more than a few :P